# Error when recreating a Client ID for an Android App in the API Console

Tags: android, google-oauth, clientid

I created a  Client ID for my Android App in the API Console specifying the package name (**com.clc.mmm.free**) and the Certificate fingerprint (SHA1). 
Then I deleted the Client ID and the API Console project where the ID was created (it was a "test" API Console project).

Now I want to **re-create the Client ID** in a new API Console project but I am getting the message: **This client ID is globally unique and is already in use.**

However I cannot find a client ID for my package/key anywhere, I even un-deleted the initial project and checked, there is no Client ID for my package, but still getting the same error!

Without the Client ID I cannot publish my new release of the app with Google+ sign-in.
Please help!

Comment: I am facing same issue.. can you help me.. I tried all solution listed below but couldn't work

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554

I had the same issue. I solved it reading the last post on this thread.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but it doesn't work in my case. I have deleted the client ID itself from the project and now when I try to recreate it I am getting This client ID is globally unique.... Like the client ID is stuck in API console database. Any other solutions?

Comment: You clicked "API Access" on the left sidebar to delete it, right? If this is not the case, I would have no clues.

Comment: Yes, in https://code.google.com/apis/console, I clicked API Access and deleted the Client ID I had created initially in a dummy project. Now I want to recreate in the real project, but it  gives me the "already in use".

Comment: I could delete and re-create other Client IDs, but not this particular one for package com.clc.mmm.free, for which I a still get the  error "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use". Any solution really appreciated....

Comment: Issue resolved today. Some back-end cleanup was done by Console API guys. Thank you.

Comment: Hi calinL, did you ask support to clean up on your account or what? All the solutions mentioned in above url didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: @awonderer Please post an actual answer not a link to a forum

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. There was google project which i previously linked with my current the android package. I removed the  OAuth 2.0 client IDs from the previous google project.

One can remove client ids from the credential tab under API manager.

After removing client ids all worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. It was not any issue on google side.

First I have added fingerprint and package without any issues. I deleted it. Tried to add fingerprint with **different package name**. Then I got the error. I realized that the problem was not related incomplete deletion of my old entry.

The issue was that **same pair of package and fingerprint** was added by android dev in different project long before.

You can add same fingerprint with different package without any problems. That could be a hint when to troubleshoot what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. It was NOT issue on google side.

After getting this error I spent 4 hours checking all my accounts, all projects in them and than checking it again. I have even asked all developers in my team if they had created any keys for our package name. Finally I have found a project hidden on "All projects" tab containing the client id I was searching for.