# Cannot re-create Oauth for the app published

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-games

I'd like to use Google Play Game Services for my Simple Hangman game published on Google Play.

I made a game service on Google Play Developer Console(in the U.S.) few months ago and didn't implement it until 2 weeks ago. While I am implementing it(do not know it matters but in South Korea), I received an error message "**unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/**" so I tried deleting my previous client ID as here said : [Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in)

However I cannot re-create new one but received this message:
**"this client id is globally unique and is already in use"**
I checked no app is using this SHA-1 key with my package name

I can re-create the Client ID for another app in Google APIs Console but not for my app published.
My implementation is working for another SHA1 key, but not for this app.

I saw post someone got helped by someone in Google here:  [Error when recreating a Client ID for an Android App in the API Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659689/error-when-recreating-a-client-id-for-an-android-app-in-the-api-console). But there wasn't written the way how.

I want to attach Google Play Game Service really(was going to implement multiplay as well). Can anyone help me please?

my app is this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pk.utman

Comment: No. I dont know how to ask..

Comment: I asked it to Google but the answer was very sad: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58849

This website is for developer issues with the AOSP Android source code not Google apps or services such as Play services. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an appropriate place to report bugs with Play Services. All I can say is that this website isn't it, sorry. Try posting on the "Google Mobile Help Forum" where Googlers are known to frequent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had recently hit a similar problem where we were unable to re-create a ClientID after removing an old one. The error was a simple 'An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it'.

We deleted the game from play services (losing all the achievements we had added) and created a new one, but that had the same problem. We created a new app with a different bundle ID and that worked fine. It seemed like the link between the Bundle ID and the SHA1 had put an entry in a table somewhere that prevented a new one being created.

The way we resolved it was to create a new release keystore, which in turn created a new SHA1. This worked fine and we were able to link everything together.

Once an app is released, Google Play will not accept an APK signed with a different keystore, so this solution is for unreleased apps only.