# This client ID is globally unique and is already in use

Tags: android, google-oauth, clientid, google-api-console

I have created Android client id for **expense.loremipsum.tracker** for my app. Actually I have created 2 id, one for by Eclipse keystore and one is for my signed key store. My application is live so I can not change package.

I have tried by deleting project and recreating project but couldn't work. Now I am not able to create client id for **expense.loremipsum.tracker**.

I refereed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659689/error-when-recreating-a-client-id-for-an-android-app-in-the-api-console). Should I contact Google? Now from any project I am getting this error **This client ID is globally unique and is already in use**

My application is live and not working Google Plus client.

### Edit

Right now I have not any Android client id regarding this **expense.loremipsum.tracker** and I am still not able to create single one for this.

Answer (score 7):

Try going here to see if you have old projects:

https://cloud.google.com/console#/project

What ended up resolving this for me is what Ketan suggested. You need to go here:

https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Then click the drop down menu in the top left underneath your name (if you don't have any, create a basic project, then go to the dropdown menu). From there, you can see in Ketan's screenshot that there is an undelete. Undelete your project.

Once undeleted, go to the 'API Access' section. If you have anything under 'Client ID for installed applications', click delete of this on the right. Then you can delete this project again.

Once that was done, I was able to recreate my game services OAuth 2.0 in the Google Play Game Services page at the regular Google Play publish page:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

Comment: Has any of this changed recently (or as in since you wrote this)? I am new to publishing on Android Play Store, and generally advice just don't match with actual console(s). Specifically, both https://cloud.google.com/console#/project AND https://code.google.com/apis/console/ link to **the same place** for me.

Answer (score 5):

No need to contact Google.

If you delete project it doesn't mean you delete client id.

You have to delete client id because it's unique.

If you have deleted project then Go to undelete>(your project) and delete client id

[image]

Comment: I have not any client id for this package and still not able to create

Comment: It may be in project which you have deleted.

Comment: I un-deleted all my deleted projects, and one by one checked API keys in all of them, none of them have any api key, but I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the https://console.developers.google.com/project
select a deleted project then in the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth. Select credentials and click delete button to deactivate the clientID.