# Google Plus sign in Android?

Tags: android, google-plus

Below is the code with which I am doing sign-in with Google Plus. Some internal error occurs. I want to know what I am doing wrong in the code.

When I use the `SCOPE:SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE`, login successfully occurs but I am not able to fetch personal details of user. I want to do login by fetching user detail using Google plus integration. If anyone has working code of Google plus sign in then please help me?

I have tried the approach from [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/). Also, I have registered this project on Google developer console.

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
                ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

            private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
            // Logcat tag
            private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

            // Profile pic image size in pixels
            private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

            // Google client to interact with Google API
            private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

            /**
             * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
             * from starting further intents.
             */
            private boolean mIntentInProgress;

            private boolean mSignInClicked;

            private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

            private SignInButton btnSignIn;
            private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
            private ImageView imgProfilePic;
            private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
            private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
                btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
                btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
                imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
                llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

                // Button click listeners
                btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
                        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
            }

            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }

            protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Method to resolve any signin errors
             * */
            private void resolveSignInError() {
                if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                    try {
                        mIntentInProgress = true;
                        mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        mIntentInProgress = false;
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                            0).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                    // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
                    mConnectionResult = result;

                    if (mSignInClicked) {
                        // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                        // resolve all
                        // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                        resolveSignInError();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                    Intent intent) {
                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                    if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        mSignInClicked = false;
                    }

                    mIntentInProgress = false;

                    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Get user's information
                getProfileInformation();

                // Update the UI after signin
                updateUI(true);

            }

            /**
             * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
             * */
            private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
                if (isSignedIn) {
                    btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
             * */
            private void getProfileInformation() {
                try {
                    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                        String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                        String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                        String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                        String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                                + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                                + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                        txtName.setText(personName);
                        txtEmail.setText(email);

                        // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                        // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                        // replacing sz=X
                        personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                                personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                                + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                        new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                updateUI(false);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            /**
             * Button on click listener
             * */
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                    // Signin button clicked
                    signInWithGplus();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                    // Signout button clicked
                    signOutFromGplus();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                    // Revoke access button clicked
                    revokeGplusAccess();
                    break;
                }
            }

            /**
             * Sign-in into google
             * */
            private void signInWithGplus() {
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mSignInClicked = true;
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Sign-out from google
             * */
            private void signOutFromGplus() {
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Revoking access from google
             * */
            private void revokeGplusAccess() {
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                                    updateUI(false);
                                }

                            });
                }
            }

            /**
             * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
             * */
            private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
                ImageView bmImage;

                public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
                    this.bmImage = bmImage;
                }

                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                    String urldisplay = urls[0];
                    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return mIcon11;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you also added the SHA-hash of your certificate to the google api-access? check logcat for certificate problem. It was my problem last time

Comment: what your LogCat is showing? there should be some errors or warnings

Comment: no, logcat does not show any thing but a toast is shown saying an internal error.

Comment: But when i add the addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE) the Googleapiclient is connected but not able to fetch user detail.

Comment: even in "All messages (no filters)" category? check also the info level

Comment: I'm not sure if you resolved this or not, but make sure that you generated a Client ID AND an API Key... this was my downfall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
```

to this:

```
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it may not help but I think i may have a solution that can help you get on the right path to fix it.

I just fixed my own problem with this and i have the following checklist for you:

- Ensure you are using debug.keystore SHA-hash or whatever keystore you wish to use
- Ensure your package name in both your manifest and class files is the exact same as the one in the developer console.
- Check if the google developers console has the correct APIs active for your use
- Fill basic required data on consent screen section in developers console
- If you have logical issues within your code look at how the official suggested implementation is from the tutorial site or further look at the github link ([here](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android))
- Try re-compiling and re-making the project in both eclipse/your IDE & developer console

Brief explanation around internal error suggests that your implementation of the Google sign in API is not correct, more information ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login)). My own problem was based on the logic I used when resolving the connection within my code. I firstly re-built my project and then changed the implementation and found some small errors in my use of the API and corrected them to make it run. 
Hope this helps you too.

Comment: while creating New Client Id on google api Console I am getting below error
Duplicate fingerprint
The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client.

Comment: Thats weird. I'll have to look into that. I got my app to work :) just fetches basic JSON data as a library but its still something. One thing that I did uncover was that it has to be solved through a diagnostic process. Here's [one](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554) possible solution. The other interesting possible case i found was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659689/error-when-recreating-a-client-id-for-an-android-app-in-the-api-console).

Apparently deleting the old client ID may cause issues but you might wanna try-

Comment: -to delete the client ID and rename the build path on which you have your app. I get that this is a long process but there's not enough documentation for me to be able to pinpoint it especially with the issue being related to google's console. In-case I did not ask before, did you delete your old Client ID and then remake? Try refreshing the page after that is done just to ensure it. Sometimes google console bugs out. Don't worry about the problem not being found in one step, i'll run you through as many steps that can help us get to a solution as you may need.

Comment: Sorry for comment spam but I got another possible solution: Try un-delete all your old Client ID's, remove the API's they are connected to and re-delete them. If that works then it may be an issue related to google's console management where they seem to have bugs around deleted Client ID's with API linkages tied to them. I read on a code.google link that I referred you to earlier that sometimes that occurs.

Comment: I have deleted every project and it's client id from my Google API console , but still , i'm getting this error, i don't how to fix this issue.